# Problems with "Open with Windows Explorer"

Tags: open-with-explorer

We have had users report the inability to open a document library item in SharePoint 2007 using the "Actions" -> "Open with Windows Explorer" option.  We use Windows 7 OS and Office 2010.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: And if that browser is IE, is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use 32-bit Internet Explorer to get this option to work correctly.  The reason, as I understand it, is that it relies on ActiveX controls that are not available in 64-bit flavors.

If you go to the start menu and type 'internet explorer' in the bottom text box, you should see 2 shortcuts.  One of them says "Internet Explorer (64-bit)".  Make sure you **do not** use this one to launch IE.

Answer (score 0):

Adding site to IE 11 trusted sites list made the "Open with Explorer" control visible
(SharePoint 2010, Windows 7, IE 11 32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

1. Update your current video driver.
2. Run System File Checker (SFC) to check your files.
3. Scan your PC for Virus or Malware infections.
4. Start your PC in Safe Mode to check for startup issues.
5. Start your PC in a Clean Boot environment and troubleshoot the issue.